# I want the VisibleDropDown to be showing after moving data from one sheet to the other

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below I'm moving data from one sheet to the other. in the title I want arrow of autofilter to be visible/showing, so I can filter every column after moving the data.

I want to be able to filter the columns of all moved data.

```
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()

Dim wsName As String
Dim mySh As Worksheet
Dim newsh As Worksheet
Set newsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rapport")
Set mySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rapportbron")

Dim countselected As Integer: countselected = 0
Dim col_name As String
Dim col_count As Integer: col_count = 4

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

newsh.Unprotect
newsh.Cells.Clear
newsh.Columns("D:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
newsh.Columns.UseStandardWidth = True
newsh.Rows.UseStandardHeight = True
newsh.Rows.RowHeight = 15
newsh.Columns.ColumnWidth = 8.71

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
col_name = Me.ListBox2.List(i)
countselected = countselected + 1

For a = 1 To mySh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If mySh.Cells(1, a).Value = col_name Then

'copy the data from raw to new worksheet created

For b = 1 To mySh.Cells(Rows.Count, a).End(xlUp).Row
newsh.Cells(b, col_count).Value = mySh.Cells(b, a).Value

'Autofit Columns
newsh.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Format Table Headers
newsh.Cells(1, col_count).Resize(1, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(233, 233, 233)
newsh.Cells(1, col_count).Resize(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
newsh.Cells(1, col_count).Resize(1, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
newsh.Cells(1, col_count).Resize(1, 1).VerticalAlignment = xlBottom

Next b
col_count = col_count + 1
End If
Next a
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Data Loaded", vbInformation
newsh.Activate
newsh.Range("C2:G6").Select

Selection.Locked = False
Selection.FormulaHidden = False

newsh.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
newsh.Range("D5").Select

End

End Sub
```

Comment: I got a bit dizzy trying to follow the flow of your code logic but, assuming the data table headers start in cell `A1` on the `rapport` sheet after the copying, then insert the following line of code just after your `Next i` line: `newsh.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter`